# Trigger.io: Facebook API Login

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk, trigger.io

The js sdk of Facebook has a `fb.login` function for which is used for login functionality.

but I can't find anything that trigger.io has this functionality.

I have managed to use `forge.facebook.authorize` but the user always go to the unnecessary page "You have already authorized".

Can we bypass the "You have already authorized" Page since the users already know that he already authorized with that application. Or we should have something like `forge.facebook.login` functionality to just have an oauth dialog in our mobile app.

I hope trigger.io can answer this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

isnt that what forge.facebook.hasAuthorized() is for?